# MacOS Notarization on command line unable to create authentication session

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel-extension, xcrun, notarize

Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session

[MacOS notarization on command line returning 'unsupported url' when getting status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412609/macos-notarization-on-command-line-returning-unsupported-url-when-getting-stat/58586587#58586587)

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.xx" --username “xx@mac.com” --password "xxx" --asc-provider "xx" --file xxx.kext.zip
```

The above command giving me below error, if anybody faced similar issue please let me know how to resolve the issue

```
altool[4753:1282542] *** Error: Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

couple of things need to be done.

1) manage app specific password(https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage)
   https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/927

2) try to type all commands manually so that command line should not have escape character(before I tried to copy paste commands)

Answer (score 0):

First try to run this command to make sure your user name and password are correct.

> xcrun altool --list-providers -u aaaaaaa@gmail.com -p aaaaaaaaaa

the user name for the account is the apple id username that created the app specific password. (it is not the name of app specific password created. that is just for housekeeping)